# iPad Pro 3rd Gen Launch Image

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

We're trying to bring iPad Pro 3Gen support to our app, but to our surprise, there is no slot in the Image Asset Launch Image set to add launch images for iPad Pro 3Gen. Many answers suggest that we use a launch storyboard, but the problem is that we have different images for iPhone X and regular iPhones, and there is no way to differentiate between them using a regular image set, while the Launch Image set cannot be displayed by a UIImageView. Moreover, we cannot add code to the launch storyboard view controller.

Given the conditions: 
1. There need to be iPad Pro 3Gen support
2. Images for iPhone Xs and other iPhones need to be different as they currently are in Launch Image asset

How should we approach this issue? I tried to find answers online but they do not seem to help.

Comment: The iPad Pro 3rd gen is the same size as the iPad Pro 2nd gen. Do you already support that? From [Get ready for the new iPad Pro](https://developer.apple.com/ipad/) - *"Your app will run in Full Screen Display Mode on iPad Pro if your project’s base SDK is set to iOS 12.1 or later and you have a Launch Storyboard."*.

Comment: Hi Edward, why don't you use UIImageView and one image for all? Even if you want to use different images, you cannot add code but don't use launch storyboard in this case...use your first viewcontroller as launch storyboard?